# Remove bottom border of tabhost in ICS (ActionBarSherlock, v4 support lib)

Tags: android, android-tabhost, actionbarsherlock

I'm on Android ICS (4.0.3) using ActionBarSherlock and the v4 support library. I am trying to figure out where the bottom border of the tab host is defined and can be customized/removed.

[image]

Referring to the screenshot below, I'd like to remove the bottom border for an active tab. The active tab view itself doesn't have a bottom border, the bottom border seen on the screenshot (circled in red) seems to be coming from the underlying tabhost or somewhere. I just could not find the style or attribute to overwrite yet. The same goes for the very light, ~2-3px drop shadow that you can see beneath the tab section. Did not see where it's defined either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme add

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```